# How can I listen to a Subscription and when recieving something, use the cache to save it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

When you do a `Query`, you can just pass a `update` function:

```
<Query
  {...}
  update={(cache) => {
    // do your cache logic
  }}
 >
```

But on a `Subscription`, there isn't a `update` argument. wat do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using the `<Subscription>` component, the renderProps function gets called every single time there's an event/update.

```
<Subscription {...} >
  {({data, loading}) => {
    // Do something here
  }}
</Subscription>
```

You could even use the function without the HoC, but it seems like it would take some work: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.subscribe

Comment: The render function is a no-no for me, as I just want to update cache so other `<Query>` components get updated. I think the other solution may be what I want. Any idea how to integrate it?